# for loop in TWIG with string concatenation?

Tags: twig

How can I output this HTML block with a nested TWIG counter variable {{ i }} like: eco-item-2.jpg, eco-item-3.jpg and eco.benefits.item.header.2, eco.benefits.item.header.3 and so on…?

```
{% for i in 0..3 %}
    <section class="eco-benefits">
        <img src="{{ asset ('img/eco-item-1.jpg') }}" class="th">
        <dl>
            <dt>
                {% trans from 'eco' %}
                    eco.benefits.item.header.1
                {% endtrans %}
            </dt>
            <dd>
                {% trans from 'eco' %}
                    eco.benefits.item.text.1
                {% endtrans %}
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </section>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using the [`~`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) operator:

```
{% for i in 0..3 %}
    <section class="eco-benefits">
        <img src="{{ asset ('img/eco-item-' ~ (i + 1) ~ '.jpg') }}" class="th">
        <dl>
            <dt>{{ ('eco.benefits.item.header.' ~ (i + 1))|trans(domain = 'eco') }}</dt>
            <dd>{{ ('eco.benefits.item.text.' ~ (i + 1))|trans(domain = 'eco') }}</dd>
        </dl>
    </section>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Something is wrong or missing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0speissvx5m7pax/Screenshot%202017-03-20%2022.02.20.png?dl=0

Comment: Indeed, the starting single quotes where missing. Sorry for that.